# How to use php curl to set cookie file in server?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, drupal

I have to authenticate the user from wordpress to drupal. i am using php curl to pass the username and password to drupal user login url and setup random cookie for every user but cookie is not generating in the server.

$login_url = 'http://xxxxx.com/drupal/user/login';

```
// Preparing postdata for wordpress login
$data = "name=". $username."&email=".$usermail."&pass=".$user_pass."&form_id=user_login&sso=1" ;

$cookie_file= '/xxx/yyy/serverpath/user_cookies/'.rand().'.txt';




// Intialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Url to use
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    // Set the cookies for the login in a cookie file.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
    // Set SSL to false
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    // User agent
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $http_agent );
    // Maximum time cURL will wait for get response. in seconds
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    // Return or echo the execution
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    // Set Http referer.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url );
    // Post fields to the login url
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // Save the return in a variable
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);  



    /*
    ** if you need to visit another url, you can do it here.
    ** curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'a new url address or a file download url' );
    ** $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    */
    // Close the cURL.
    curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: I'm fairly confident Cookies are for the browser.

Comment: @Doug Already written drupal module to submit the user and login

Comment: How to track the curl set cookie bug

Comment: Curl is acting as a browser, but if you set cookie in a curl connection it won't create cookie in user's browser and that is what you are looking for I believe.

Comment: Yes how to set a browser cookie